# href links not working when nested in data section

Tags: html, wordpress, href, custom-data-attribute

So I'm designing a site that utilizes parallax scrolling and the HTML5 data attribute. The problem is that nested in one of the data sections (data-slide), I have a link, and it doesn't seem to work unless I place it outside of the data-slide.

url: http://ericbrockmanwebsites.com/dev3/ (at the bottom of the page, in "projects")

Here's the markup:

```
<div class="slide" id="slide4" data-slide="4" data-stellar-background-ratio="0">
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="span10 offset1">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="span3">
                <div class="slideno">
                Projects
                </div> <!-- slideno -->
            </div> <!-- span3 -->

            <div class="span7">
            <div class="gridContainer">
                <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
                'post_type' => 'page',
                'post_parent' => 0,
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order' => 'DESC',  
                'posts_per_page' => 999)); // how many posts to show

                     x = 0;
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
                $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                <div class="view view-tenth"> 
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('grid-image'); ?> 
                    <div class="mask"> 
                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2> 
                    <p></p>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="info">Explore</a> 
                    </div> <!-- mask -->
                </div> <!-- view view-tenth -->
                    <?php $x++; ?>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

                </div> <!-- gridContainer -->
            </div> <!-- span7 -->
                </div> <!-- row -->
        </div> <!-- span10 offset1 -->
        </div> <!-- row -->
    </div> <!-- container clearfix -->
</div><!-- Slide 4 -->
```

Any advice on what I am doing wrong or how to get around this?
Thanks, as always!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this one?

```
input type="button" name="Release" onclick="document.write('<?php the_permalink() ?>');" value="Explore"
```

Its a different approach of the href.